# In Materialize CSS, how do you center Font Awesome icons in the card-panels?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, materialize, responsive

I've been having an issue regarding the alignment of both my content and the cards used from the Materialize CSS library.  I've been trying to find a way to keep my Font Awesome icons centered in the designated card panels *relative* to the aspect ratio.  Is there something I'm doing wrong with my tags and classes?

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s3">
        <div class="card-panel teal grey darken-1 center-block">
            <center><a class="icon" href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-4x"></i></a></center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s3">
        <div class="card-panel teal grey darken-1 center-block">
            <center><a class="icon" href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github fa-4x"></i></a></center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s3">
        <div class="card-panel teal grey darken-1 center-block">
            <center><a class="icon" href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-4x"></i></a></center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s3">
        <div class="card-panel teal grey darken-1 center-block">
            <center><a class="icon" href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-codepen fa-4x"></i></a></center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-image:url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/c7/5d/e1/c75de1208bf12c355ad1ba4264787b18.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  color:white;
  position:relative;
}

.card-panel {
 display: flex;
 text-align: center;
}

.icon {
  text-align: center;
}

.fa {
  position: relative;
}
.fa:hover {
  color:white
}
```

Right now on desktop, the icons on my card panels remain offset to the left on each card:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWhix.png

The same is seen on mobile, except this time the icons are not only offset, but they're also not responsive to the width of each card panel:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0PS6.png

So in order to accomplish this formatting task, how would I be able to center each of the icons in alignment with each given card panel *and* make it responsive for varying screen sizes?  Finally, can this be accomplished using properties that are already a part of HTML and CSS, or would I have to implement frameworks such as Flexbox or CSS Grid for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I removed  `display: flex;` from card-panel

```
.card-panel {
 text-align: center;
}
```

It worked for me

Comment: Removing "display: flex;" at least realigned the card-panels of the page, but the icons still remain in the exact position they were in prior.  My goal here is to have the icons position themselves centered to each card-panel regardless of the card's width in response to the screen size.

Comment: In this codepen I created to try to understand your problem and the fix I proposed, the icons are centered in the card-panel regardless of window size on my windows machine https://codepen.io/chartman4/details/vdRaGm  Not sure what I am missing.